# How to programmatically comment out code-cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, nbconvert

I'm doing automatic conversion `.ipynb` -> `.py` using `nbconvert`.

There are some cells that I'd like to exclude from execution in final `.py` script, so I need some programmatic way to manipulate cells before conversion to `.py` script.